# How to prove every open set is Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am currently using Stein's book to self study measure theory and now I'm stuck on proving this property of Lebesgue measure below.

Property: Every open set in $\mathbb R^d$ is measurable

The book just says this immediately follows from the definition of Lebesgue measure (a subset $E$ of $\mathbb R^d$ is Lebesgue measurable, is for any  $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an open set $O$ with $E\subset O$ and $m^*\left(O\smallsetminus E\right)<\varepsilon$), but I'm not sure how the property is derived from the definition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't just take $\mathbf{O}=E$?

Comment: Depends how the author defined "$\subset$". If $E$ has to be a real subset from $O$ there is some more work to do.

Comment: So m*(O\O)=m*(∅)=0?

Comment: @Gono . Stein better mean that  $\subset $ doe not mean proper subset, else he is saying that $E$ is not measurable when $E=\Bbb R^n.$

Comment: There are many equivalent ways to define "Lebesgue-measurable set". It is helpful to be familiar with several of them. There  also seems to be a modern teaching style that omits the mention of  "inner measure",  which I find perplexing.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet good hint :-)

Answer (score 2):

Modern usage is that $E\subset E.$  The author must be using this, and not requiring that $E\subsetneqq O.$ Because in the case $E=\Bbb R^n$ there is no  $O$ such that $E\subsetneqq O\subset \Bbb R^n$, but if  $E=\Bbb R^n$ then $E $  $ is $ measurable. So  we can let $O=E,$ and it should not be hard to prove that $0=m^*(\phi)=m^*(O \backslash E).$

Comment: I strongly dispute that this is "modern usage".  It's certainly a usage that exists, but it is far from dominant.

Answer (score 0):

> a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$
> is Lebesgue measurable, if for any $\varepsilon>0$
> there exists an open set $O$
> with $E\subset O$
> and $m^{∗}(O\setminus E)<\varepsilon.$

So $E$ is Lebesgue measurable if its outer measure differs from an open set's by less than $\varepsilon.$ Well, if $E$ is open, then it's equal to its interior, which I'll denote by $E^\circ$. Then we can write $E\subset E^\circ$ and all that is left is show that $m^*(E^\circ\setminus E)<\varepsilon $, which is already done, since they're the same set and therefore $m^*(E^\circ\setminus E)=0<\varepsilon$.